# Save and Load into UserDefaults in Swift

Tags: swift, userdefaults

I want to save the value drawn in Paint in UserDefaults. Also I want to import saved values into the load button event.I am using RxSwift and RxCocoa.

```
struct Paint: Codable {
    let image: Data?
}
```

This is Paint code.

```
saveButton.rx.tap.subscribe(onNext: {
            let  paint = Paint(image: Data())
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
            let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(paint)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "paint")
            print("save")
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
        
        loadButton.rx.tap.subscribe(onNext: {
            if let saveData =  UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "paint") as? Data {
                guard let data = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Paint.self, from: saveData) else { return }
                print("load")
            }
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

I wrote the code like this. Which part is wrong?

Comment: you are passing an empty data object to your `Paint`
 initializer. Btw don't use `value(forKey:)` `UserDefaults` has a specific method to load data called `data(forKey:)`

Comment: @LeoDabus Then do I have to save the data in the imageView? How do I avoid being passed to an empty object?

Comment: Why don't you simply write your data to disk instead of using UserDefaults. Note that it is not meant to persist data

Comment: You should never use the UI to pass data around. Just keep a reference to your image. If you need to convert the image to Data just use jpegData or pngData methods to convert your image to a data representation.

Comment: @LeoDabus, I'm not at all arguing with that statement. But seek clarification - I use UserDefaults to store an IAP purchase where I have no server, so Apple really controls it. I also would call that "data" that is persisted - at least until a new device is introduced or the existing device is wiped clean. I'm **not** trying to hijack the question, but could you elaborate on what you mean by "persist data"?

Comment: Ah. Your last comment answered my concern enough. Peace!

Comment: @LeoDabus I'm going to save what I drew on the drawing board. Do we still need jpeg Data or png Data then?

Comment: @earth Which framework are you using? Please edit your question and show a [mcve]

Comment: The question was corrected. I don't use anything other than Rxswift and Rxcocoa. I think the paint is not initialized, how should I do it?